# При position fixed все элементы сдвигаются влево, а должны оставаться на месте?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, position, fixed

Как сделать, чтобы меню было фиксированное и элементы оставались на местах?
Когда там ещё и логотип (он у меня на пк), то вообще в него немного залазит.
На имгуре фото до прокрутки и после ней:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKvGt.jpg

```js
window.onscroll = function shownavbar() {
  var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
  if (window.pageYOffset > 1) {
    navbar.classList.add('navbar_fixed');
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove('navbar_fixed');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('../img/main-bg.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.m_auto {
  margin-left: 99px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar_fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url('../img/logo.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #000;
}

.burger {
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  float: right!important;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.burger::before {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  float: right!important;
}

.burger::after {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  float: right!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <!--Background with css-->
  <div class="m_auto">
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
      <a href="#" class="burger"></a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">о нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```